trouble with ggplotly in rmarkdown
I have a code that works great, but I would lik it to be interractive.
The problem is when I apply ggplotly it dosent print on the html document.
This piece of code works great:
### ---- Display the sales graph (TW vs LY) ----
  if (exists(division_cleaned, Lista_Graficos_Ventas_Por_Division)) {
    grafico_division <- Lista_Graficos_Ventas_Por_Division[[division_cleaned]]$grafico
    
    if (!is.null(grafico_division)) {
     print(grafico_division)
    } else {
      cat("No graph available for this division.\n")
    }
  }

But when I apply ggplotly like this it stops wotking:
### ---- Display the sales graph (TW vs LY) ----
if (exists(division_cleaned, Lista_Graficos_Ventas_Por_Division)) {
  grafico_division <- Lista_Graficos_Ventas_Por_Division[[division_cleaned]]$grafico
  
  if (!is.null(grafico_division)) {
    # Convertir el gráfico ggplot2 en un objeto plotly para interactividad
    ggplotly(grafico_division)
  } else {
    cat("No graph available for this division.\n")
  }
}


May be its because im in a rmarkdown loop?

It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a minimal but complete and runnable code and a snippet of your input data shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.

But as you are using a (for??) loop you might have a look at Using ggplotly and DT from a for loop in Rmarkdown.
